# Find the number of people using average scores

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Say we know that a class of people has a total average of 91.2 out of 100 on a test. We know that there are 21 girls that average 92.0 out of 100. For boys, we know that the average for all the boys is 90.5.

Using this information, how would we go about finding the total number of boys in the classroom? I can’t seem to figure it out and it’s bugging me. I am also not sure how to properly tag this post under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N_b,N_g$ denote the numbers of boys and girls, and $S_b,S_g$ denote the total *sum* of their grades.

- $N_g=21$ girls that average $92$ means $S_g/N_g = 92$ so you can find $S_g$.
- Boys average $90.5 = S_b/N_b$
- total average is $$\frac{S_g+S_b}{N_g+N_b} = 91.2$$

plug $N_g,S_g$ in and you have 2 variables in 2 equations.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to decide what the variables are and write down equations that describe what you know.  Most of these "word problems" just come down to that.  Here we know that there are $21$ girls and their average score was $92$.  Their total score war $21\cdot92$.

We aren't told how many boys there are, so let the number of boys be $b$.  Their average score was $90.5$ so their total score was $90.5b$.

Now the total score of all the students is $90.5b+21\cdot92$ and their average score is $91.2$  There are $b+21$ students altogether, so this means that $$\frac{90.5b+21\cdot92}{b+21}=91.2$$

Now I'm sure you can finish it off.

Comment: Thank you so much!